# React.js this.props undefined unless page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So, I have the following problem, I'm trying to show all the posts the user has made in the user's profile. If I start from log in and go to the profile it gives me the error that this.props.user[0].id is undefined. However, if I refresh the page (sometimes twice), it works perfectly.

I have search online and I only see cases that are opposite (props undefined when refreshing) and I could not find a solution.

This is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Card, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText} from "reactstrap";
import Withuser from "./Withuser"

class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      thoughts: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getShares()
  }

  getShares = () => {
    const user_id = this.props.user[0].id
    console.log(this.props.user[0].id)

    axios(`http://localhost:7001/api/profile/shares/${user_id}`)

    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data)
      this.setState(state => ({
        thoughts: res.data,
        loggedIn: !state.loggedIn
      }))
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.setState({ error: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { thoughts } = this.state
    return(
    <div>
      <h1>Your posts</h1>
      <ul>
        {thoughts.map((thought, index) => {
          return (
            <Card className='thoughts' key={index}>
              <CardBody>
                <CardTitle>{thought.user_name} posted at {thought.createdAt}</CardTitle>
                <CardText>{thought.body}</CardText>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Withuser(Profile, { renderNull: true });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Withuser component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const withUser = (Component, options = { renderNull: true }) => props => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null)
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null)
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (!token) return
    axios('http://localhost:7001/api/profile', {
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token,
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        const id = response.data.id
        setUserId(id)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setError(true)
        console.log(error)
      })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios(`http://localhost:7001/api/users/${userId}`)
      .then(response => {
      
      setUserData(response.data)
    })
  }, [userId])

  if (!userData && options.renderNull) return null
  return <Component {...props} user={userData} />
}

export default withUser
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is the console when refreshing:
[image]

Can you see where the error can be?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: How does `WithUser` HOC look like?

Comment: Seems like it's from what was passed to Profile. Can you check Withuser HOC?

Comment: Thank you guys, I have edited the post and added the Withuser component.

Comment: Can you include `withUser` Compoent

Comment: Still did not find the solution for this, it is something weird, because if I made a small change in any of these two components, like a console.log, it works, then I try again and it doesn't....

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed via adding a loading state to the HOC so you don't render wrapped components until the data is fetched.

```
const withUser = (Component, options = { renderNull: true }) => props => {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token) return;
    setLoading(true); // set the loading state before api call is made
    axios('http://localhost:7001/api/profile', {
      headers: {
        'x-access-token': token,
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        const id = response.data.id;
        setUserId(id);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        setError(true);
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false); // reset loading state after api call is done
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true); // set the loading state before api call is made
    axios(`http://localhost:7001/api/users/${userId}`).then(response => {
      setUserData(response.data);
    }).finally(() => setLoading(false)); // reset loading state after api call is done
  }, [userId]);

  if (loading) return null; // Or render a loading indicator
  if (!userData && options.renderNull) return null;
  return <Component {...props} user={userData} />;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Clarity, I had it to false at the very beginning but it gives me the error cannot read property of null (instead of undefined)

Comment: @Guerreri88 ah I see now. I've edited my answer with a better suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @Clarity, I've tried but I get the error "cannot read property 0 of null" refering to this.props.user

Answer (score 0):

It is because in useEffect, the axios is an async call,

```
const withUser = (Component, options = { renderNull: true }) => props => {
  ...
  useEffect(() => {
    axios(`http://localhost:7001/api/users/${userId}`)
      .then(response => {
      
      setUserData(response.data)
    })
  }, [userId])
```

Quick and reliable solution is to add default props on Profile component

```
Profile.defaultProps = {
  user: [],
}
```

and check necessarily

```
  getShares = () => {
    if(props.user.length === 0) return
```

Comment: Hey Nikko, thank you for your answer, I've been reading about defaultProps and I'm still not sure how I can apply it to my app. The reason that I need the props is to get the userId from the user that is logged in. How can I do that with defaultProps? this is not clear for me... sorry I'm a bit new in coding....

Comment: what i suggest is only to prevet undefined on initial load, so allowing it to be updated with correct props